# How to linearize this constraint: a summation of a product of a integer with a binary

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

I have to linearize the following constraint,

$$ \sum_{i \in V_C} \sum_{j \in V} \sum_{k \in K} y_{ik} \cdot x_{ijk\ell} \leq I_\ell \qquad  \forall \ell \in V_D $$

where $y$ is a integer variable smaller than $v_i$ and $x$ is a binary variable. I have found some other question about this but there they do not have the combination of a integer value with a binary and no summation. Does anyone know how to linearize this constraint?

Comment: It seems that it is not avoidable to avail integer variables and binary variables.

Comment: May we assume that $y_{ik} \geq 0$?

Comment: @calculus, he's not trying to eliminate integer/binary variables, he's simply trying to eliminate products of the form $y_{ik}\cdot x_{ijk\ell}$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant O.K. One question: Did you define $v_i$ ? Maybe I´m blind, but I can´t see it.

Comment: I assumed $v_i$ is constant. If it is not, just replace it with a value that you know will bound $y$. This cannot be done without constant bounds.

Comment: $v_i$ is indeed a constant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following assumes that $y_{ik} \geq 0$.

First, let's introduce a new set of variables $z_{ijk\ell}$:
\begin{gathered}
\sum_{i,j,k} z_{ijkl} \leq I_\ell \qquad \forall \ell \\
y_{ik} \cdot x_{ijk\ell} = z_{ijk\ell} \qquad \forall  i,j,k,\ell
\end{gathered}
I hope you don't mind that for brevity I've dropped the index sets. This is equivalent (in $x$ and $y$) to
\begin{gathered}
\sum_{i,j,k} z_{ijkl} \leq I_\ell \qquad \forall \ell \\
y_{ik} \cdot x_{ijk\ell} \leq z_{ijk\ell} \qquad \forall  i,j,k,\ell
\end{gathered}
This works because when the original inequality is feasible, we can always *choose* to have equality hold: but if there is slack in that inequality, we could distribute that slack across the values of $z_{ijk\ell}$ without changing equivalence.

Now that we've done that, we can use this equivalence:
$$y_{ik} \geq 0, ~~ y_{ik} \cdot x_{ijk\ell} \leq z_{ijk\ell} \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
0 \leq z_{ijk\ell}, ~~ y_{ik} - v_i ( 1 - x_{ijk\ell} ) \leq z_{ijk\ell}$$
If $x_{ijk\ell}=0$, then $z_{ijk\ell}\geq 0$ will be active. If $x_{ijk\ell}=1$, then the second constraint will be active, and it will be equivalent to $y_{ik} \leq z_{ijk\ell}$.

So the final conversion is
\begin{gathered}
\sum_{i,j,k} z_{ijkl} \leq I_\ell \qquad \forall \ell \\
y_{ik} - v_i  (1- x_{ijk\ell}) \leq z_{ijk\ell} \qquad \forall  i,j,k,\ell \\
0 \leq z_{ijk\ell} \qquad \forall  i,j,k,\ell
\end{gathered}